# Properties not being passed to bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In the below code I'm getting a `NullPointer` at line `private File ratesFile = new File(ratesFilePath);` in my `myClass.java`.

As far as I can see my properties file is fine, I'm importing it fine into my `.xml` configuration and passing the property to my class OK.  My getters and setters seem OK to me too.  Any pointers on why my properties aren't being passed to my class?

Spring Batch 2.1.8

myClass.properties:

```
rates_file_path=/opt/rates
rates_file=rates.txt
```

myClass.xml:

```
    <bean id="myClassProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:conf/myClass.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="myClass" class="com.stuff.blah.myClass">
        <property name="ratesFilePath" value="${rates_file_path}/${rates_file}" />
    </bean>
```

myClass.java

```
public class myClass implements Tasklet, InitializingBean {

    private String ratesFilePath;
    private File ratesFile = new File(ratesFilePath);

    public String getRatesFilePath() {
        return ratesFilePath;
    }

    public void setRatesFilePath(String ratesFilePath) {
        this.ratesFilePath = ratesFilePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: When the `private File ratesFile = new File(ratesFilePath);` statement is executed (at construction time), the `ratesFilePath` has not been injected yet, hence the `NullPointerException`.  So either use constructor injection, or remove this inline initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In your `myClass`,

```
private File ratesFile = new File(ratesFilePath);
```

is an error raising code.

Both `ratesFilePath` and `ratesFile` is initialized when the constructor is called.

Because `ratesFilePath` does not have any values to initialize with, it is set to `null`.

And when `ratesFile` is trying to be initialized, it will use the `ratesFilePath`, which is `null` and will raise a `NullPointerException`.

To fix this, first set your `ratesFile` to `null`;

```
private File ratesFile = null;
```

And set `ratesFile` on the setter method of `ratesfilePath` after making sure that path is not `null`.

```
public void setRatesFilePath(String ratesFilePath) {
    this.ratesFilePath = ratesFilePath;

    if(ratesFilePath == null) ratesFile = null;
    else ratesFile = new File(ratesFilePath);
}
```